# Navigation to the screen is too slow. It takes almost 5 seconds to open a screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, expo

When I try to navigate from Signin screen to the Home Screen it takes almost 5 seconds to open Home Screen. You click on the Sign in button and wait so much until it will navigate to Home. The interesting part is that only the buttons that navigate to the Home page cause this issue. I mean it happens only when you want to navigate Home Page. It seems the problem is with Home Page. Here is the code:

Component file that will be included inside the Home Screen

```
const Posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    views: "260 Views",
    comments: "19 Comments",
    published: "14h ago",
    image: require("../img/img1.png"),
  },

...  
];

const Posts = props => {
  return (
    <Content>
      {Posts.map((item, idx) => {
        return <DataContainer {...props} key={idx} item={item} />;
      })}
    </Content>
  );
};



 const DataContainer = ({item, navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Card style={styles.card}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Post")}>
        <CardItem cardBody>
          <Image
            source={item.image}
            style={styles.img}
          >
            <Text
              style={styles.text}
            >
              {item.title}
            </Text>
          </Image>
        </CardItem>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <CardItem>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon
              active
              name="eye"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            <Text style={{color: '#4286f4'}}>
              {item.views}
            </Text>
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon
              active
              name="chatbubbles"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            <Text style={{color: '#4286f4'}}>
              {item.comments}
            </Text>
          </Button>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <Text style={{color: '#4286f4'}}>
            {item.published}
          </Text>
        </Right>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Home Screen File

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}>
        <CommonHeader {...this.props} />
        <Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor: '#4286f4'}}>
          <Tab
            tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
            heading="Popular"
            activeTextStyle={{color: '#4286f4'}}
            '#EEE'Style={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
            textStyle={{color: '#333333'}}
          >
            <Posts {...this.props} />
          </Tab>
          <Tab
            tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
            heading="New"
            activeTextStyle={{color: '#4286f4'}}
            Style={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
            textStyle={{color:'#333333' }}
          >
            <Posts {...this.props} />
          </Tab>       
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there missing something? Why it loads so slow?  Also it's slow on both ios and android devices but  The slowest one is on Android mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I had this issue, I found that my images had too high of dimensions and my app was trying to scale them down by itself, causing a huge slowdown. Try to decrease the dimensions of your images and see how that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What resolution have you chosen to fix it?

Comment: Do you click the button and wait so long to navigate that screen? I am asking it because on the other screens it navigates instantly but waits for opening images. While in this issue it wits so long until navigates to that screen.

Comment: @Artur I decreased the dimensions of mine to 300 x 375 from 1931 x 2415. Mine was definitely only on that screen.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say dimensions instead of resolution. It was downscaling the image and that was slowing it down! I edited my answer to fix my error :)

Comment: Ok I got it ;) Are you using expo as well? It seems Expo has tones of troubles with images.

Comment: Sadly, I don't program with react. I am a simple Android programmer using Java!